# Is it possible to call a custom ajax event after removing a file from a managed_file field?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a custom form with a managed_file field element. I'd like to call an ajax event after removing a file (clicking the REMOVE button).

Is there a way to expand the existing ajax callback for the remove button?

What I'm trying to do is fire a custom ajax event after clicking the REMOVE button on a managed_file element to remove an element from the dom.

Comment: Which Drupal version?

Comment: Drupal 8. What I'm trying to do is fire a custom ajax event after clicking the REMOVE button on a managed_file element to remove an element from the dom.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same in D7 a while ago and I discovered a JS only solution is not possible. You need to add an ajax command to the Drupal callback.

Here's a [similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/280883/calling-a-js-function-after-managed-file-has-completed-uploading) to yours. This one is about the upload button and you want the remove button.

In D7, the upload and remove button were handled by the same function and when I look at the D8 class of the [managed file](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Element%21ManagedFile.php/class/ManagedFile/8.7.x) I also see only one callback: [uploadAjaxCallback](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Element%21ManagedFile.php/function/ManagedFile%3A%3AuploadAjaxCallback/8.7.x). So it might be worth checking that out.